# Log in tries timeout

Tags: php

I have a ticketing help desk and I limited the login tries to 10. After 10 times, user can't login again! I want to set a timeout for login tries attempt.

So if someone tried to login and did wrong for 10 times, can't login again from that IP or for that username for only 5 or 10 mins. I have a `config.php` file and I have this:

```
 define('LOGIN_TRIES',10);
   //and in my login.php page i have this:
    //limit login tries.
    if (isset ( $_SESSION['hit'] ) ) {
    $_SESSION['hit'] += 1;
    if ($_SESSION['hit'] > LOGIN_TRIES){
        echo "<p><i class='fa fa-lock fa-2x pull-left'></i>Access Locked.</p>";
        include("includes/footer.php");
        exit;
        }
    }else{
    $_SESSION['hit'] = 0;
    }
```

Comment: Ok but what's the question here?

Comment: the question is HOW to set timeout for login tries. because if someone do wrong for 10 times , he cant login again for EVER from that browser. so?

Comment: Since you are using the session to apply this restriction, all a hacker has to do is to clear their cookies and the restriction is removed. You need to do this via IP address.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you could improve this code, but basic logic would be to set a timestamp when user gets locked, then check if the lock timed out.

If so reset `hit` to `0`

```
if (isset ( $_SESSION['hit'] ) ) {

    /* If user is locked check for timeout, set to 10min */
    if( isset($_SESSION['locked_time']) && 
      ($_SESSION['locked_time']+600 ) <= time()) ){
         $_SESSION['hit'] = 0;
         unset($_SESSION['locked_time']);
    }

    $_SESSION['hit'] += 1;

    if ($_SESSION['hit'] > LOGIN_TRIES){
        $_SESSION['locked_time'] = time(); // set last locked time here
        echo "<p><i class='fa fa-lock fa-2x pull-left'></i>Access Locked.</p>";
        include("includes/footer.php");
        exit;
    }
}

else{
   $_SESSION['hit'] = 0;
}
```

Comment: it not working for me. i put this in my `index.php` file where my login form is and the page isn't opening

Comment: @Aria You will have to modify the code for your needs, I do not know about the rest of your code.

Comment: modify where exactly?

Comment: @Aria Try to debug the code yourself, don't just paste the code and expect it to work.

Comment: im not a pro in php , can you tell me where to change EXACTLY mate?

Answer (score 0):

You are protecting against a brute force attack.  I found the following link useful. Use a database table to record log in attempts and their times, the username or email address, and in your case, an IP address (not performed in the linked example below).

See section 3 - Brute Force function 
http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL

so the query in the example selects all instances within a certain time frame (possible, because you record the time of each log in attempt).